# MySQL row and column select

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, datatable

I got a table structure in my HTML

[image]

Needs to populate the data as rows and columns, some columns having a value "1"

Fixed 10 Rows and 10 Columns and there are multiple tables

So I just created a database like the following

```
ga_id (pk)   |   A1  |  A2  |  A3 ......
-------------+-------+------+-------------
 125         |  1    | 0    |  0 ..........
-------------+-------+------+--------------
 126         |  0    | 1    |  1 ...
```

I got the following questions

1. For achieving the same, is my approach is correct ?
2. I need to check whether a column or a row is fully occupied with a value "1"

   for eg:-
   Case block D4  then I need to check D1,D2,D3..... D10 having the same value ie 1

And  A4,B4,C4,D4.......J4 values having the same value

Hope my question is clear,

Comment: 1. No. See normalisation. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet.

Comment: 2. See 1. Then get back to us.

Comment: can you please give me a link or little idea about that process ?

Comment: Do you have multiple tables like this, or just one?

Comment: See your solution for the problem makes me cry.

Comment: I have multiple tables like this.... admin can add n number of tables

Comment: What is your objective?  Are you doing linear algebra?  What specific problem are you trying to solve by retrieving rows or columns which are uniformly 1?

Comment: actually its a game, multiple use can unlock a block. And if an user unlock the last element of a row or a column , they will get 10 points and that row / column will lock for ever. Thats the objective

Answer (score 1):

As a comment, the "*correct approach*" is whatever approach solves your issue. While normalization and the [third normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) are concepts that are battle tested and definitely worth mastering, if the current structure solves your particular issue, go with it.

A possible, normalized DB structure would be:

- Table columns: column_id, name
- Table rows: row_id, name
- Table  tables: table_id, name
- Table table_rows_columns: table_id, row_id,
  column_id, value

Comment: If the current structure solves your particular issue, you probably shouldn't be using an RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

By way of example, a normalised environment might look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(id INT NOT NULL
,x INT NOT NULL
,y CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,val INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,x,y)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(101,2,'B',1),
(101,2,'I',1),
(101,4,'D',1),
(101,5,'I',1),
(101,7,'D',1),
(101,7,'H',1),
(101,8,'G',1);
```

Comment: With all respect - this is **not a normalized** structure.

Comment: With all respect, it is.

Comment: Indeed it is - it is the first normal form. This structure is closer to the excel sheet you were talking about than to the third normal form we all thought you were referring in your snarky comments

Comment: @TudorConstantin That's strange. This appears to be identical to the 4th table in your own sample schema.

Comment: the DB structure I propose enables the business to change the naming scheme for columns/rows by updating just a row in one of the tables columns/rows, for each of the entity they want to modify. So, it might appear, but it's not quite the same.

Comment: Get rid of the `id` column; change to `PRIMARY KEY(x,y)`.

Comment: Does it matter whether the word "normalized" applies?  It is a valid way to store a sparse 2D table.  (after getting rid of `id`)

Comment: Mapping to HTML is another matter.

Comment: @RickJames No. There are multiple 'tables'.